# Compound component in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8

I'm making a battle card game for an uni project (Hearthstone)

The "minion" cards on board have health and attack, and those are constantly changing, I'm trying to make a compound component that would be a center `ImageIcon` with two "squares" at the bottom left and right, representing the card's current Health and Attack, and one at the top left, representing its cost, all these as `StringProperty`

I'm really clueless on how to approach this, maybe a coumpound component isn't even necessary

This is an example of how a hearthstone card looks :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a StackPane.  Put the image on the bottom, and then an AnchorPane on the top.  Put a Text in each of the three cornerns, and bind the textProperty() of each to one of the StringProperties.  Something like this:

```
public class BattleCard extends Application {

private static Label label;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    label = new Label();
    label.setText("Waiting...");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(new CardPane());
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 350, 420));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public class CardPane extends StackPane {
    public CardPane() {
        ImageView cardImage = new ImageView(new Image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ljQH.png"));
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        getChildren().addAll(cardImage, anchorPane);
        Text costText = new Text("Cost");
        Text healthText = new Text("Health");
        Text attackText = new Text("Attack");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(costText, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(costText, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(healthText, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(healthText, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(attackText, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(attackText, 0d);
        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(costText, healthText, attackText);
    }
}
```

}